# Javascript replace character with backslash

Tags: javascript

How do I replace `+` with `\+` using the replace method?

```
console.log("abc+pqr".replace("+","\+"));
```

This gives the original string `abc+pqr` but I want `abc\+pqr`.
How do I get this?

Comment: You first need to understand how to embed a single `\\` character inside a string.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the backslash:

```js
console.log("abc+pqr".replace("+","\\+"));
```